# What the point of the dnx-mono package in NuGet?

Tags: asp.net, mono, dnx

When developing an ASP.NET 5 app, I can install the mono runtime into it via NuGet. For example, the latest to date dnx-mono.1.0.0.rc1-update1.

As far as I've tested, the thing is the actual runtime I'm installing on, for example, Linux via DNVM tool to run ASP.NET apps on it.

If I installed the package into a project, I can't then chose it in project properties, nor I can chose it when publishing into a folder - only Windows clr versions are available.

So what's the point of installing it right into the application project?

Or maybe it is not intended to be installed into a project, but exists solely for DNVM could find and pick it up?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. It is used by DNVM and your application should never reference it directly.